# WebRTC Firefox to Chrome video call not working

Tags: webrtc, signaling

My WebRTC app works fine when I connect two of the same browsers, but when I try a combination neither respond to each others signaling messages. Something probably worth mentioning is that I have not implemented TURN, however I don't see why that should make a difference so I'm not going to change that unless I'm fairly certain it will.

I don't have much of a clue where the error lies, so I will just add code on request for the sake of readability.

Comment: I still have this exact problem. Chrome can't see video from Firefox, but Firefox does see video from Chrome. No errors, all callbacks fired, handshake process done all the way, but no video at the end, for 1 party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enable DTLS-SRTP (Firefox only supports DTLS-SRTP) by passing the following to the PeerConnection constructor:

```
{ 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': 'true'}]}
```

See [this page](https://webrtc.org/web-apis/interop/#) for more details.

Comment: https://webrtc.org/web-apis/interop - although it no longer references DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement

Answer (score 0):

You have not really described what goes wrong with the signaling. No error messages and so on.
But based on the fact that you only see the fault when using two different web browsers I would recommend using Adapter.js that have been somewhat promoted from webRTC.

Link to webRTC demo that shows on the interoperability using Adapter.js(page also contains a link to Adapter.js):http://www.webrtc.org/demo

Direct link to 
[adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/stable/samples/js/base/adapter.js)

Comment: I have already added adapter.js and seeing that it works fine when I connect to Firefox browsers, I don't think that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off your firewalls to check if it fixes the problem.
In my case (Windown 7), default windows firewall didn't allow UDP for Private Inbound Connection Setting and Firefox + Chrome p2p connection just didn't work.

Hope it helps.