# WebRTC works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I read several other questions on a related issue, but none answered my question. I have an odd issue where I am able to use WebRTC to audio chat from chrome to firefox but not firefox to chrome.

Basically, when a user wishes to audio chat, he/she clicks a button `#audioChatBtn`, which uses `getUserMedia()` to setup a stream. The thing is, clicking `#audioChatBtn` from Firefox doesn't fire the `onaddstream` callback on Chrome, but clicking the button from Chrome fires `onaddstream` on Firefox. Thus, I can audio chat from Chrome to Firefox but not the other way around. I have been trying to figure this out for several hours, but I'm hoping maybe someone here has an answer.

Relevant source:

```
var configuration = {
    'iceServers': [
        { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        { url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
        { url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
        { url: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' }
    ]
};
var pc = RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
var myStream = null;
var currentAudioIndex = 0; // Number of created channels
var myAudioEnabled = false;

// send any ice candidates to the other peer
pc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
    if (evt.candidate)
        $(document).trigger("persistState", { mode: 'rtc', 'candidate': evt.candidate });
};

// let the 'negotiationneeded' event trigger offer generation
pc.onnegotiationneeded = function () {
    pc.createOffer(localDescCreated, logError);
}

// once remote stream arrives, play it in the audio element
pc.onaddstream = function (evt) {
    console.log('creating and binding audio');

    var idx = (currentAudioIndex++);
    var audioElement = $('#audio' + idx);

    if (audioElement.length == 0) {
        var audio = $('<audio id="audio' + idx + '" autoplay>');
        $('body').append(audio);
        audioElement = $('#audio' + idx);
    }

    var audioObject = audioElement[0];
    attachMediaStream(audioObject, evt.stream);
};

function localDescCreated(desc) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
        $(document).trigger("persistState", { mode: 'rtc', 'sdp': pc.localDescription });
    }, logError);
}

function logError(e) {
    bootbox.alert("Audio chat could not be started.");
}

function hasGetUserMedia() {
    return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
              navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

server.onPersist = function(msg) {
    if (msg.mode == "rtc") {
        if (msg.sdp)
            pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp), function () {
                // if we received an offer, we need to answer
                if (pc.remoteDescription.type == 'offer')
                    pc.createAnswer(localDescCreated, logError);
            }, logError);
        else
            pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate));
    }
}



// On click, start audio chat from this user.
$('#audioChatBtn').click(function() {
    if (!hasGetUserMedia()) {
        bootbox.alert('Audio conferencing is not supported by your browser. (Currently only supported by Chrome, Firefox, and Opera web browsers.)');
        return;
    }

    if (myAudioEnabled) {
        myStream.stop();
        displayAlert('Streaming closed', 'Audio chat is off');
        $('#audioChatBtn').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');

    } else {
        getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true }, function (localMediaStream) {
            myStream = localMediaStream;
            pc.addStream(localMediaStream);
            displayAlert('Streaming...', 'Audio chat is enabled');
            $('#audioChatBtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
        }, logError);
    }

    myAudioEnabled = !myAudioEnabled;
});
```

## What I've tried

- Tried using `'optional': [{ 'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': 'true' }]` in the configuration after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435233/webrtc-firefox-to-chrome-video-call-not-working)
- Tried creating a new RTCPeerConnection() each request
- Tried using native browser functions instead of [adapter.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webrtc/blob/master/samples/web/js/adapter.js).
- Explored Web Audio API instead of `getUserMedia()`

Comment: Dear downvoter, the close reason that you provided states that the question "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." My question includes all these elements.

Comment: Out of topic question, i want to implement webRTC but is it possible to make user1 contact user2 if both have their IDs instead of loading .showing all connected users to the server?

Comment: maybe [peer.js](http://peerjs.com/) will be easier to use then reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @arao6 Cool.. I've already +1'd this, so hopefully someone will be able to help.

Comment: @DmitryMatveev Peerjs uses node.js, we're using ASP.NET with SignalR as our signaling server

Comment: Does a fully audio and video call work? Have you tried NOT Trickling the ice candidates? Could you post the relevant SDPs?

Comment: Also, for STUN, Firefox cannot use DNS names. It will not be able to really gather ice candidates given those addresses. Try `stun:23.21.150.121` as a stun server in FireFox to see if that helps any...though if you are on the same network, it does not really matter anyways.

Comment: Thank you to all for the help, I figured out the solution; turns out nothing was wrong with my code, it was a browser bug.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Good to know. To whom does `23.21.150.121` belong to? A DNS lookup shows that it belongs to someone's Amazon EC2 instance

Comment: not sure, it is just a public one for testing that I have seen around. Obviously, you should not use any public servers in production(even Google's).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Firefox has supported FQDN stun names for quite a while now.

Comment: @jesup, good! I just have not kept up with the release notes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox does not currently support onnegotiationneeded, because we currently don't support re-negotiation of an existing connection.  All addStream/addTrack and a single createDataChannel (if you want to use them) need to be done *before* createOffer() or createAnswer.  You *can* createDataChannel() after you connect, if you created on before createOffer.

Adding a stream after they're connected won't work.

An (annoying) alternative is to create a new set of PeerConnections to replace the old ones (using a DataChannel in the old pair as a signaling channel for lower latency)

Resolving this is high on our priority list, but will take a few more releases.

Comment: Apparently fixed in ff 38: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/webrtc-in-firefox-38-multistream-and-renegotiation/

Comment: Yes, that landed in Fx38 and is now in Firefox release

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of debugging, I came to realize that the bug has nothing to do with my code but has to do with Firefox's implementation of WebRTC. Firefox doesn't trigger the `onnegotiationneeded` callback, so I have to do it hackily using a timeout (and *hope* that the stream information has been relayed to the remote client before the function fires). Obviously, this is a firefox bug and I will report it, hoping that they fix the bug in the next build.

```
        getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true }, function (localMediaStream) {
            myStream = localMediaStream;
            pc.addStream(localMediaStream);
            displayAlert('Streaming...', 'Audio chat is enabled');
            $('#audioChatBtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');

            // Need this for Firefox
            if (webrtcDetectedBrowser == 'firefox')
                setTimeout(pc.onnegotiationneeded, 5000);

        }, logError);
```